# Google checkout notification in classic ASP

Tags: google-checkout

Any one help me on how to get Google checkout notification in classic ASP.

Answer (score 0):

Start by browsing the Google Checkout ASP sample library:

http://code.google.com/p/google-checkout-classicasp-sample-code/

You can also try the Checkout Merchant integration forums:

http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!categories/checkout-merchant/integration-troubleshooting